# Passing parameters from python/flask to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a python/flask application that I'm creating. I am also using javascript on some parts of it. The current setup I have is that when I render the template, I pass along any additional javascript that needs to be on the page.

```
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',
    more_js = '/static/js/example.js',
    more_js_script = 'example_js_to_execute();')
```

It ends up on the page that more_js is the src of a script tag and more_js_script is executed in a script tag. Is there a better way to do this?
There's also times I need to pass a parameter to the more_js_script that is a string, but because of the formatting

```
more_js_script = 'example_js_to_execute('parameter');
```

will end up like

```
<script>example_js_to_execute(&#39;parameter&#39;);</script>
```

on the actual page and not execute correctly. Do you have any tips on how to restructure what I'm doing or execute what I have with parameters?

Comment: Is there some reason not to just include the JS inline in the template itself, or just include a separate JS file in the index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `more_js_script` not to be automatic escaping.

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping